# What is the Reason for Gap Between DIVs

Tags: css

I have a simple HTML page as shown below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            BODY { margin:0px; padding:0px; background-color:#000000; color:#FFFFFF;}
            /*H1 { margin:0px; }*/
            .t-head { padding:10px; background-color:#0000FF; }
            .t-body { background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#000000; /*padding:10px;*/}
            .t-footer { padding:10px; background-color:#0000FF; color:#FFFFFF;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="t-head">Header content</div>
        <div class="t-body">
            <h1>Content Header</h1>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
            nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
            pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
            culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
        <div class="t-footer">Footer content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The body of the page has three parts - a header DIV (t-header), a body DIV (t-body) and a footer DIV (t-footer).  For ease of discussion, I've styled the background of the BODY to be black.  If you view this page in a browser, there is a gap (i.e. a horizontal band of black) between the header DIVand the body DIV.  This behavior is consistent across IE, Chrome and Firefox.

I know the culprit of the gap - it's the margin of the H1 tag.  If you uncomment the H1 style from the styles section of the page, you'll see that the gap goes away.  Alternatively, you can leave the H1 style commented out and uncomment the padding style on the t-body class and the gap will go away.  What I don't understand is **why** the H1 margin causes a gap between the t-head DIV and the t-body DIV.  My understanding of CSS (which is obviously incorrect) is that the H1 margin should be calculated from the top of the t-body DIV.  I also don't understand **why** adding padding to the t-body DIV fixes the issue.

Can anyone explain the reason why the H1 margin seems to be causing the gap between the t-head DIV and the t-body DIV?  ...also, why does adding padding to the t-body DIV resolve the problem?

Comment: A jsFiddle to show your issue : http://jsfiddle.net/AvLTL/

Comment: HerrSerker's answer is correct, but this has already been asked, and answered, on SO. [Read the similar questions answers here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996693/why-do-the-p-and-h1-elements-cause-gaps-in-my-layout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is collapsing margins.

Look at this article, especially the chapter 'Collapsing Margins Between Parent and Child Elements': http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins and you might see.

---

You can cancel the collapsing margins by using `overflow`with a different value than `visible`, e.g. `overflow: hidden` or `overflow:auto`.
http://jsfiddle.net/5w4gp/

```
.t-body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

---

If you don't like the `overflow` technique, you could add

```
.t-body {
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

to the `.t-body`.
http://jsfiddle.net/68785/

---

There's also a third solution utilizing `float` and `clear`: http://jsfiddle.net/z2RNF/

```
.t-head {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.t-body {
    clear: both;
}
```

---

Why do these work? They prevent the collapsing vertical margins to 'touch' each other.

Here is the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: See also: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/margin/, specifically the last example.

Comment: Hi, can you explain it? In this case, did you mean t-head and t-body are joint? But the OP did not use margin, he used padding.

Comment: No, not `.t-head` and `.t-body` are joint. It's the margins of `.t-body`(which is zero) and the margin of the first `h1` inside `.t-body` (which is the browser default) touch. If they do, they collapse and shown above the `t.body`. Collapsing means, they do not have a margin of their own, but share one margin, which is the maximum of both margins.

Comment: But what is the margin of h1? Is it 0 default? If I set it as 0, the collapsing disappears.

Comment: If you do not set a margin by your won onto the `h1` there is always a browser default. In Chrome you can see it in the element inspector. On Chrome it is `margin: 0.67em 0` as default. Other browsers may differ. If you don't want the to differ, use a reset.css or normalize.css like one of these http://www.cssreset.com/

Answer (score 2):

**That's just the default CSS box model for block elements**, the margin of children elements collapse.

If you want to use margin top to place your title, you need to set your .t-body element a `display: inline-block;` property.

As you can see there : http://jsfiddle.net/AvLTL/1/

More specifications here : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to having an element placed in a div whose padding extends past the edge of a div would be for said  element to overlap into the other div, which would not help 'divide' the two divs. The interpreter would rather make space between two divs than overlap content between the divs.

So, your h1 has enough padding to extend past the edge of your body div. This causes the gap. When you increase the padding of the body div, it gives it enough room to keep the whole h1 inside of it. Experiment with this by increasing paddings by a few pixels at a time.

(  I would provide a graphic but I'm on my phone :[  )